# camera2 api video is being stretched on some devices like onepluus one

Tags: android, video, mediarecorder

I am using Camera2 api from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video.
I want to use camera in full screen.
My Surfaceview is still stretched in one devices like oneplusone.
I have tried various options from forums, but no luck.
Please let me know if anybody has solution.

Comment: have you tried to manipulate the aspect ratio?

Comment: Yes. With 4/3 and 16/9 too.